# Clearing a form field in Javascript upon click

Tags: javascript, forms

Sorry for the newb question in advance! I'm making a Calculator app in Javascript and am having a hard time getting the "C" (clear) button to clear the field. EDIT: To clarify, the Clear button should not only clear the field but also everything held in memory so that I can start a fresh calculation. `<input type="reset" value="C"/>` clears the field but holds the last buttons I've pressed in memory.

```
    <script>
      input = "";

      function handleClick(data) {

        input += data;
        document.getElementById("output").value = input;
        console.log(input);
      }

      function evaluateExpression(data) {
        input = document.getElementById("output").value = eval(input);
      }

      function clear(data) {
        input = data;
        input = document.getElementById("output").reset(); 
        console.log(input);
      }

    </script>

    <div id="calculator">

      <form>
        <input type="text" id="output" />
      </form>

      <button onclick="handleClick(1)">1</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(2)">2</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(3)">3</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(4)">4</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(5)">5</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(6)">6</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(7)">7</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(8)">8</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick(9)">9</button>
      <button onclick="clear(0)">C</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick('+')">+</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick('-')">-</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick('/')">/</button>
      <button onclick="handleClick('*')">*</button>
      <button onclick="evaluateExpression()">=</button>
    </div>
```

The "clear" function just does not want to work. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 7):

Do reset on form . [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

```
document.getElementById("frm").reset();
```

or Set the value of textbox like this

```
 document.getElementById('output').value = "";
```

Comment: document.getElementById("form").reset(); gives me an error of: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reset' of null "

Comment: While 'document.getElementById('output').value = "";' DOES clear the field, when I press the next number it appends the next number to what I've just cleared. Ex: press 4 then C. Field clears. Press 2. 42 appears.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the built-in `reset` type?

```
<input type="reset" value="C"/>
```

This would have to be inside the `<form>`.

Comment: Hmm, upon testing, while that clears the field it does not clear what's in javascript's memory. After clearing, when I press "7" for example, it will hold the last action I pressed ("+" in my case), then add 7 to it. For example I did 2+2 which gave me 4. Then I press clear, press 7 then it gives me 11.

Comment: it will not work if form contains a field like:
<input type="text" value="abc" />

after reset the form, it'll still contain "abc" in the text field...

Answer (score 2):

For resetting form input fields, this worked for me:

```
 document.getElementById('elementId').value = "";
```

If you are trying to reset elements on the page that isn't a form, this worked for me:

```
 document.getElementById('elementId').innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just set the text of output to a blank string?

( or )

more likely if your doing a calculator set it to 0?

```
document.getElementById("output").value = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of clearing the value of an input field

```
<input id="entry" type="text"></input>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

var entry = document.getElementById("entry"),
    clear = document.getElementById("clear");

function clearfield() {   
    // EDIT: place code for clearing anything else that would be affected here
    entry.value = "";
}

clear.addEventListener("click", clearfield, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VCj7W/)

And here is an example of using [form.reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/form.reset)

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="entry" type="text"></input>
</form>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

var clear = document.getElementById("clear"),
    form = document.getElementById("myForm");

function clearfield() {
    // EDIT: place code for clearing anything else that would be affected here
    form.reset();
}

clear.addEventListener("click", clearfield, false);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4YzS6/)

Also, inline javascript is considered bad practice and you should consider a method such as [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/element.addEventListener) instead.

i.e. `onclick="doit();"`

> Why use addEventListener?
>
> addEventListener is the way to register an event listener as specified
>   in W3C DOM. Its benefits are as follows:
>
> It allows adding more than a single handler for an event. This is
>   particularly useful for DHTML libraries or Mozilla extensions that
>   need to work well even if other libraries/extensions are used. It
>   gives you finer-grained control of the phase when the listener gets
>   activated (capturing vs. bubbling) It works on any DOM element, not
>   just HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do [this.?](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6Wqn/1/)

then try this code,

```
function clear(data) {
         document.getElementById("output").value=data; 
      }
```

Comment: @PradeepKumarPrabaharan Glad that helps PPK! :)

Answer (score 0):

On C button click, clear the output value

```
 document.getElementById('output').value = "";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        if(this.value == 0)
        {
            this.value='';
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Cange the "input" to #YourFieldId, and get rid of the if inside, but keep the this.value=' ';

That is the best way to clear fields on click if you can use jquery...

You could also always have a condition to check the input and then clear like the code above clears input fields that have a '0' in them.